# Convert 3 axis vectors to axis/angle

Tags: c++, math

I have this source code which rotate three axis aligned on X, Y and Z:

```
    Quaternion<float> orientation = transform.getOrientation();
    Vector3<Vector3<float>> axis(
        orientation.rotate(Vector3<float>(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
        orientation.rotate(Vector3<float>(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
        orientation.rotate(Vector3<float>(0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    );
```

From 'axis' variable, I would like to re-build the quaternion. I have a quaternion constructor which allow me to construct it from an axis and an angle.

How can I do that ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice Wikipedia page describing [Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). Specifically, the section "Conversion to and from the matrix representation."

Be sure to pay attention to the following point, quoted from that page, "One must be careful when converting a rotation matrix to a quaternion, as several straightforward methods tend to be unstable when the trace (sum of the diagonal elements) of the rotation matrix is zero or very small."

In general, converting from the rotation matrix (which is essentially what you have constructed) to a quaternion is a bad idea. A rotation matrix must be a special orthogonal matrix, which is a very small subset of all possible 3x3 matrices. You will almost always lose some precision when computing the matrix so that it won't be precisely orthogonal. Indeed, this is one of the reasons that quaternions are preferred for representing rotations in 3 dimensions. In general, if you can avoid the conversion and just use quaternions you will be better off.

There is an algorithm on that page that gives a stable method that may be good enough for your purposes. But from personal experience I can tell you that you should expect to lose some precision in the operation in most cases.

Comment: Also, try tThe Matrix and Quaternion FAQ:
http://cxc.cfa.harvard.edu/mta/ASPECT/matrix_quat_faq/#Q55